# monit fails to support dbus session

Tags: display, shell, environment-variables, dbus, monit

I am trying to use monit to monitor and automatically issues like crashes, memory leaks and cpu hotspinning.

For one application - one that uses DBus (serving and calling funcs) just will not start.

It uses GDBus which errors with `dbus-launch` not availiable – which indeed is true as the targets system is quite oldish and there that command does not exist yet exist.

**But** running the binary from console works - just works - I guess this is because of DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is set properly - but this is not the case in the shell being spawned for monit?

**How can I make the shell spawned by monit aware of a shell variable (i.e. DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be security *feature* - [this git commit](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/commits/cd545838378517f84bdb0989cadf461a19d8ba11) resolves the issue by not trashing the env array.

https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issue/6/dbus-session-bus

---

A dirty workaround for those stuck to monit 5.4 or earlier (last tested):

A dirty hack to get a session bus from other processes env variables (only tested with a single user):

```
#! /bin/sh
DBUS_ADDRESS=`grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/*/environ 2> /dev/null| sed -e 's/\/proc\/[^\/]*\/environ\:/ /g'| cut -d ' ' -f 2`
if [ "x${DBUS_ADDRESS}" != "x" ]; then
        export ${DBUS_ADDRESS}
fi
```